# Java http post: Difference in reading bytes through curl and in java

Tags: java, android, http

I am stuck in a strange issue, I am posting some image data to a server, now I created the requested using curl and then traced back it.

Next was to create similar request in java.

The code posts raw binary image data to server, but when I compare the binary data in java to that posted by curl, there is a minute difference due to which I am getting 400 response code from server.

The difference I think is in few dots.

Below is the request generate by curl (linux).
[Generate by curl](http://pastebin.com/92eBwz0g)

Now here is the request generate by Java, when I read bytes.
[Click here](http://pastebin.com/RFNzxaGf)

Java code looks something like this:

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os);
    out.println("POST /1izb0rx1 HTTP/1.1");
    out.println("User-Agent: curl/7.35.0");
    out.println("Host: requestb.in");
    out.println("Accept: */*");
    out.println("Content-Disposition:inline; filename=test.png");
out.println("Authorization: Basic YW5kcm9pZDpUZXN0dGVzdDExISE=");
out.println("Content-Length: "+"24143");
out.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
out.println();            
out.println("."+imgBytes);
```

Any idea what can be causing this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: It is all very vague. How many bytes do you post in both cases? And how many bytes are received?

Comment: What do you mean by a generated request?

Comment: `Difference in reading bytes`. Who is reading bytes?

Comment: I dont get what you are asking, this complete chunk of data is posted on to server.

Comment: You you really think we would inspect that data? We are not computers. If you post image bytes in two ways and the received bytes are not equal in both cases then say so. What else is the problem?

Comment: Just view the first line of the image byte in both cases, you will easily find a difference, switching tabs will show you the difference.

Comment: Where am i looking at? At a request? Where? On server side? On client side? Why so difficult? If you have troubles posting an image to a server then show your Android code and show the server code.

Comment: Why dont you put the first few lines of the image in two code blocks here? That would make it easy to see the difference.

Comment: You are viewing client side code. Android snippet is already provided. Server side I cant share.  There is nothing difficult, I have provided the curl output which is working, for same image with exact headers, Android output (client side) differs. In both cases raw bytes are read, so this should not happen.

Comment: You did not post full android code. Especially nobody can see what is the type and what is in `imgBytes`.

Comment: `"Content-Length: "+"24143"` ? A hard coded content length? Why?

Comment: `In both cases raw bytes are read`. Who is reading raw bytes where? But you should send the raw bytes of the image. You are not doing that now.

Comment: Its hard coded because I am testing with same image, but no matter what, it isn't working. I or my code is reading raw bytes. I have saved the bytes in string (imgData), check the last line of android code. Also tried with writing bytes on stream using ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: I will have to leave now, its quite late here.

Comment: Saving bytes in a string is strange. You should put them in a byte array.

Comment: Moreover you cannot send raw bytes with PrintWriter.

Comment: There is nothing here that reads bytes. Unclear what you're asking. The line terminator in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`, not whatever `println()` gives you. Don't try to implement HTTP yourself. Use `HTTPURLConnection` or a library.

Comment: @EJP : That was the first thing I did, and since it was messing things up, I had to do like this.

Comment: If you only would post full code instead of talking about it.

Comment: `Don't try to implement HTTP yourself`. Of course everybody should give it a try. And OP nearly succeeded.

Comment: `I am getting 400 response code `. That is only because your Content Length does not match with the amount of bytes you send. Not because you try to upload a corrupted image.

Comment: Please show your curl command.

Comment: If you fill String imgBytes in the right way with content it works.

Answer (score 1):

So,

I got it working, the problem was that certain classes on Android are broken and not behaving as the way they behave on core Java.

The same code that was working on Java, wasn't working here, reason being, a change in header occurring here (On Android).

This issue is very well mentioned here also:
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1862

Thus I was facing a similar issue, and adding external updated jars were conflicting with the ones on Android.

Finally I used a small HTTP Request library: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

The code is below:

```
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.post(url);
    request.authorization("Basic "+ah);
    request.part("file", fName+".png", "image/png", new File(file));
    request.part("title", "test");
    if(request.code()==201) {
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      request.receive(sw);
      onMedia(Media.parse(new  JsonParser().parse(sw.toString()).getAsJsonObject()));
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Do not use PrintWriter to send raw bytes.

Comment: I said I already tried ByteArrayOutputStream, after that I did it like this. There wasn't any change in the data being sent. My first priority is to fix this up, after that I can move to more standard approach.

Comment: You are not commenting on not using PrintWriter. Did you try without? Please show full Android code.

Comment: You were correct, using byte array writer, this was solved, but after that there were few other issues. I am writing an answer below that finally worked.